# How to save a string for later use?

Tags: objective-c, string, save, compare, last-modified

I am currently working on having a file update from a remote server. I am able to download the file and save it to the documents directory. The file has a "Last-Modified" tag and I am using it to check if the file needs to be updated. But my question is, how do you save the string with the tag for later use? Later I want to compare the saved string with the another string with the current "Last-Modified" tag. If they are equal the file doesn't have to be updated but if they're not equal I will download the new file.

Sorry for bad English, correct me and any help is appreciated. Have been struggling with this for a while!

**EDIT:**

```
NSDictionary *metaData = [test allHeaderFields];

//NSLog(@"%@", [metaData description]);

lastModifiedString = [metaData objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];

NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:lastModifiedString forKey:@"LastModified"];
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];

NSString *savedString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"LastModified"];

if (![lastModifiedString isEqualToString:savedString])
{
    [self downloadNewFile];
}
```

Download link to files: [Archive.zip](http://cl.ly/2a2e0T1U1D3u0c3L3V2e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or Core Data to persist a value.

**EDIT:**

It is not working because you are saving the new value before retrieving it.  You'll need to move

```
NSString *savedString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"LastModified"];
```

above

```
[standardUserDefaults setObject:lastModifiedString forKey:@"LastModified"];
```

Now you'll be comparing the new file value against the old user defaults value.

Comment: @Peter_DeWeese I have tried using NSUserDefaults but it doesn't quite work for me. I've added my code to the question if you want to have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Next time just snip out the critical portion and include it in your post.  I'll do that for you right now and then edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you want to compare the Last Modified dates to see if they are the same?

I think the best way to do this would be to save the date (as a string) in a [Property List](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html). If you are making an iPhone app you can create a property list with a string with the code below. This code checks if a file already exists and if it does, it reads from it, and if it doesn't, it creates one and writes to it.

```
// Get the path to the property list.
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *pathToPlist = [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfilename.plist"];
// Check whether there is a plist file that already exists.
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToPlist];

if (!fileExists) { 
    // There is no file so we set the file up and save it.
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
    [newDict setObject:yourStringWithTheLastModifiedDate forKey:@"lastModified"];
    [newDict writeToFile:pathToPlist atomically:YES];
}

} else {
    // There is already a plist file. You could add code here to write to the file rather than read from it.
    // Check the value of lastModified.
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToPlist];
    NSString *lastModifiedDate = [persistentNonResidentData objectForKey:@"lastModified"];

    // Add your own code to compare the strings.
}
```

Or I may have misunderstood your question and that may not be what you are looking for at all lol.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this was not exactly what I was looking for.